# The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Name' on type

Tags: c#, odata

I'm returning different entity when odata request contains $select query. Here is my Get method:

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
        if (Context == null)
            Context = MainContext.CreateInstance();
        var products = Context.GetEntities<Product>();
        if (queryOptions.RawValues?.Select != null)
        {
            var goodProducts = MakeGoodProductList(products); // Type of entity is GoodProduct
            return Ok(goodProducts);
        }
        return Ok(products);
   }
```

I'm getting following error when request is `https://localhost:44326/Products?$select=Name`

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Name' on type 'GoodProduct'.

How can I solve this issue without creating Name property in `GoodProduct` class?

I'm setting `SelectExpand` and `Select` to null from `ODataQueryOptions` and `ODataRawQueryOptions`, but they aren't helping:

```
typeof(ODataQueryOptions).GetProperty(nameof(queryOptions.SelectExpand)).SetValue(queryOptions, null, null);
typeof(ODataRawQueryOptions).GetProperty(nameof(queryOptions.rawQueryOptions.Select)).SetValue(queryOptions.rawQueryOptions, null, null);
```

Comment: Why would you pass a `Select` query in your URI? Are you trying different way of SQL injection?

Comment: @KJSR, No, it is OData select: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue by resetting `RequestUri`:

```
var requestUri = queryOptions.Request.RequestUri;
var uri = requestUri.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, requestUri.AbsoluteUri.Length - requestUri.Query.Length);
queryOptions.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
```